# IPhone app - invoke function on incoming call

Tags: iphone, events, notifications

I have a piece of code (my app) which I want to run for each incoming call in the iphone.

So I'm looking for a function like: On Before Incoming Call ();

is there anything like that?

Answer (score 2):

You should check the applicationWillResignActive: method in your UIApplicationDelegate.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillResignActive:

Answer (score 1):

Check the UIApplicationDelegate method

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

In case of incoming telephony interruption this method will be invoked!